# Value of function as $x$ increases from $2$ to $2+\frac{\pi}{10}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have a function
$h(t)=cos(\frac{\pi*t}{4})$
I want to find its approximate value as t increases from 2 to 2+(1/10pi).

I start off by finding the value of the function at t=2.
This is cos(pi/2), which is 0.

Then to find the value at 2+(1/10pi) I differentiate the function which results in:
$\frac{-\pi}{4}*-sin(\frac{\pi*t}{4})$
Then I plug in (1/10pi), which results in pi/4-sin(1/40). This is wrong.
I'm not sure of what I should be doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, we know that:

$$\text{y}\left(x\right):=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\cdot x\right)\tag1$$

So, when $x=2$ we get:

$$\text{y}\left(2\right)=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\cdot2\right)=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=0\tag2$$

And when $x=2+\frac{1}{10\pi}$ we get:

$$\text{y}\left(2+\frac{1}{10\pi}\right)=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\cdot\left(2+\frac{1}{10\pi}\right)\right)=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{1}{40}\right)=$$
$$-\sin\left(\frac{1}{40}\right)\tag3$$

And we know that when $x\approx0$ we get:

$$\sin\left(x\right)\approx x\tag4$$

So:

$$-\sin\left(\frac{1}{40}\right)\approx -\frac{1}{40}\tag5$$

But:

$$-\sin\left(\frac{1}{40}\right)=-0.0249974\dots\tag5$$